# Query for searching text in Firebase android

Tags: android, firebase

How can I wrote query in firebase like "%a%" in android  firebase?

I tried the following solutions but not working 
startAt(text).endAt(text)

Please any suggestions?

Comment: Are you talking about Firebase Realtime databas? Show the code you have that does not work?

Comment: show some code and database to know what you are querying

Comment: Yes @Erik

mRef = FirebaseUtil.getPostsRef().orderByChild("title").startAt(text).endAt(text).limitToFirst(5);

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this would be to loop through the children of a key.

```
private void SearchString(DatabaseReference mDatabase, final String criteria) {
    mDatabase.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            
            //loop the children of the the current key
            for (DataSnapshot shot : snapshot.getChildren()){
                 if (shot.getValue().toString().equals(criteria)){
                     //found the string 
                     // do something
                     //
                 }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });
}
```

Given the children are all string you could call the above procedure with your database reference and the criteria. However on a large database it could take time.

A method to make it faster is to implement Binary search , given Firebase sorts your child data.